# Persist a MySQL transaction (PDO) between two page requests?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two pages, one.php and two.php which have SELECT .. FOR UPDATE and UPDATE operations respectively.

Can I start a transaction in one.php and end it in two.php? two.php is called 2 minutes after one.php; I want my transaction (row-level lock) to last for those 2 minutes.

Comment: If it's that complex, it's probably the wrong approach.

Comment: Could be an idea to show the type of code you have in mind.

Comment: Rows locked against what?

Comment: Against updates.. (InnoDB)

Comment: of course you can. You can end it in `7jillion.php` 6 hours later. Should you, no. Wanna see me show you ?

Comment: you cant do that with mysql. But check this out http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking

Answer (score 1):

> Can I start a transaction in one.php and end it in two.php?

No.

Comment: Concise, and accurate.